# About prove this statement is true or false

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$P(x): x ≤ 0,$

$Q(x): $x^2$ = 1,$

$R(x): x $ is odd,

$S(x): x = x + 1.$

Statement:

$∀x ∈ Z, S(x) → R(x) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$

$∃x ∈ Z$ such that $Q(x) ∧ ∼ R(x) \;\;(2)$

$∃x ∈ Z$ such that $P(x) → S(x) \;\;\;\;(3)$

1. I try to let $x$ in $S(x)$ is even and odd to prove $S(x) → R(x)$, $x = (2n+1) + 1 =2n +2$ this is an even, so this statement is false?
2. The true set of $Q(x)$ is $\{-1, 1\}$, the set is not satisfactory for $~R(x)$, because $~R(x)$ is an even. Thus this is false.
3. I have no idea about this one, I find $P(x)\leq 0$, but there no result is satisfactory for $S(x)$, so this is false..?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could set your question in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Is `x 2` supposed to be $x$ squared?  If so, write it as `$x^2$`.

Comment: @David Sorry about the negligence, x 2 is x^2.

Comment: So can you change it, and see if you can improve the rest too?  Making it difficult for people to help you is not a good idea.

Comment: As for answering the question, take a close look at S(x) and see if you can figure out which values of x make it true.

Comment: @ConMan This is what I am considering now, I want to find a value from P(x) is satisfactory for S(x), but no value is suitable.

Comment: Assuming you're operating in the natural numbers, integers or real numbers, there is *no* satisfactory value for $S(x)$. How can a number be equal to one more than itself?

Comment: @David I have already change it, thank you for advice, I will be more careful in the future question.

Comment: @TomAsh You can typeset math by enclosing it in dollar signs: for example, `$x^2$` gives $x^2$. See the link that David provided for a more extensive guide.

Comment: @ConMan So S(x) is false. Ah, thank you!

Comment: @TomAsh Thanks for making the edits.  FYI - set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ can be obtained with `\mathbb{Z}`.

Comment: Additionally, $P(x) \leq 0$ is a meaningless combination of symbols. $P(x)$ is the statement that $x \leq 0$, so it is satisfied by values of $x$ that are less than or equal to 0. But the statement itself is either true or false, and doesn't have a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement,  $$∀x ∈ Z, S(x) → R(x)$$ is true because $S(x)$ is always false.

You are correct on the second one.

The third statement is also true. You may pick $x=2$ for example.

Comment: Third statement is true, for example when $x=1$.

Comment: @David Thanks for the correction .I edited my answer accordingly.